# Android Launch screen take more time than a native one for Flutter

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, launch-screen

I'm new to Flutter, and I noticed that the launch screen for Android take more time than usual for a native app, I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen)

But for IOS, everything is working fine.
Is there a way to make the launch time for Android faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter is a Cross Platform. When ever you to compare with Native then it always slower than Native Apps. Both Android and IOS handling and Behaviour are different so that why you got different for Lunching time..